# how can i pass mqtt string though javascript to convert and insert into mysql?

Tags: javascript, mqtt

i have a device that send data strings via mqtt to my mosquitto broker on ubuntu i currently use node-red to then receive these strings and use javascript function node to do everything else i need, data conversions, insert into query etc but that one thing im struggling with is i want to move away from node-red so i just have files with pure code, i have tried the code provided on npm website but i need an idiots guide haha does anyone have any idea's where i can look or anyone able to help me ? all my html files are currently displayed from an apache server

my current set up for mqtt is mosquito running on ubuntu i have enabled websockets in the configuration files with listner of 1883

mosquitto configuration

```
listener 1883
listener 1884
protocol websockets

pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d
```

mqtt code i have tried :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paho-mqtt/1.0.1/mqttws31.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  <script type="text/javascript">

var wsbroker = "localhost";  //mqtt websocket enabled broker
var wsport = 1883 // port for above
var client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(wsbroker, wsport,
    "myclientid_" + parseInt(Math.random() * 100, 10));
client.onConnectionLost = function (responseObject) {
  console.log("connection lost: " + responseObject.errorMessage);
};
client.onMessageArrived = function (message) {
  console.log(message.destinationName, ' -- ', message.payloadString);
};
var options = {
  timeout: 3,
  onSuccess: function () {
    console.log("mqtt connected");
    client.subscribe('/tracked', {qos: 1});

  },
  onFailure: function (message) {
    console.log("Connection failed: " + message.errorMessage);
  }
};
 function init() {
  client.connect(options);
 }
 </head>
 <body onload="init();">
</body>
```

Comment: This question is far too broad, you need to show us what you've tried and the error messages it produces if you want help fixing it. Also asking for guides/tutorials is off topic for Stack Overflow. (also what are you hoping to achieve by moving away from Node-RED?)

Comment: @hardillb i have updated the main post with the code that i have tried however i get the following error in chrome console:
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:1883/mqtt' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED  i use port 1883 in node-red and it works fine

Comment: Please read the following help on how to ask good questions on Stack Overflow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Also you have not included any information about how you have configured your broker (or which broker you are using).  I will guess it's mosquitto and that you haven't enabled websockets support and when you do it will be on a different port to 1883 (which is native MQTT not MQTT over Websockets)

Comment: sorry, yes it mosquito i have set a websocket.conf file in my configurations with listener 1883

Comment: Edit the question to include to config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as mentioned in the comments.

You are trying to connect to port 1883 which is the native MQTT port.

To use the Javascript client from a webpage you need to use MQTT over Websockets, you have added a Websocket listener on port 1884.

So you need to edit the code as follows:

```
var wsbroker = "localhost";  //mqtt websocket enabled broker
var wsport = 1884 // Websocket port for above
var client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(wsbroker, wsport,
    "myclientid_" + parseInt(Math.random() * 100, 10));
```

Comment: so i have updated the code to your following specifications and i now get 

WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:1884/mqtt' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
Paho.MQTT.ClientImpl._doConnect @ mqttws31.js:977

testmqtt.html:25 Connection failed: AMQJS0007E Socket error:undefined.

Comment: Have you checked that mosquitto is still running?

Comment: yes, i still have my node-red up would that be causing an issue?

Comment: Are you running the web browser on the same machine as Node-RED and the broker?

Comment: no so my node-red and broker are hosted on AWS using apache as the webserver i then connect to it via the IP but all files are set up with local host as the node-red,broker and apache are on the AWS

Comment: So you can not use `localhost` as the `wsbroker` in the webpage, because that code runs on the browser, so localhost ends up pointing to your laptop. You need to put the IP address of the AWS machine in for the `wsbroker` field. (You will probably have to open port 1884 in the AWS firewall as well)

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, how can i insert this into mysql database , as i would have though that i could use php to connect , then javascript to do the conversion and then insert function but if i add the php into the same file it errors out my mqtt WS connection

Comment: New problem -> new question